# Python MJPEG Server

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv3.0, httpserver, mjpeg

I am trying to perform vision processing on a raspberry pi and monitor the effects on a graphical interface. Using cv2.imshow really reduces frame-rate, so instead, I am trying to stream the operations to a MPEG localserver and then monitor it from chrome on a different desktop. Here is the code that I have developed:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn
from threading import Thread
import imutils
import sys

class CamHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        print(self.path)
        if self.path.endswith('/stream.mjpg'):
            self.send_response(20)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--jpgboundary')
            self.end_headers()
            while True:
                try:

                    if(frame != None):
                        pass
                    r, buf = cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)
                    self.wfile.write("--jpgboundary\r\n".encode())
                    self.end_headers()
                    self.wfile.write(bytearray(buf))
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    break
            return

        if self.path.endswith('.html') or self.path == "/":
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write('<html><head></head><body>')
            self.wfile.write('<img src="http://localhost:9090/stream.mjpg" height="240px" width="320px"/>')
            self.wfile.write('</body></html>')
            return

class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    """Handle requests in a separate thread."""


class WebcamVideoStream:
    def __init__(self, src=0):
        # initialize the video camera stream and read the first frame
        # from the stream
        self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
        # self.stream.set(3, 1920)
        # self.stream.set(4, 1080)
        # self.stream.set(15,-100)
        (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()

        # initialize the variable used to indicate if the thread should
        # be stopped
        self.stopped = False

    def start(self):
        # start the thread to read frames from the video stream
        Thread(target=self.update, args=()).start()
        return self

    def update(self):
        # keep looping infinitely until the thread is stopped
        while True:
            # if the thread indicator variable is set, stop the thread
            if self.stopped:
                self.stream.release()
                return

            # otherwise, read the next frame from the stream
            (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()

    def read(self):
        # return the frame most recently read
        return self.frame

    def stop(self):
        # indicate that the thread should be stopped
        self.stopped = True


def realmain():
    global frame

    ip = 'localhost'

    try:
        cap = WebcamVideoStream().start()
        server = ThreadedHTTPServer((ip, 9090), CamHandler)
        print("starting server")
        target = Thread(target=server.serve_forever,args=())

        i = 0
        while True:

            img = cap.read()
            img1 = imutils.resize(img, width=600)
            img2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(img1, (5, 5), 0)
            #frame = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

            frame = cv2.Canny(img, 35, 125)
            if(i == 0):
                target.start()
            i +=1

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    realmain()
```

Right now, I can run the server from my desktop and view the MPEG's fine from chrome on my desktop, but I can't run the server from my raspberry pi, and access it by typing in this url: http:// "RASPBERRY PI IP" :9090/stream.mjpg, on my desktop. When I do so, chrome merely says the webpage is not available. Even when running the server on the PI, I can't view the url on the Epiphany Browser, it just downloads the image. Was wondering if anyone had an answer to this problem.

Also, is there a faster way to decompress and recompress the jpg before sending it to the server?

Comment: Can you try making *ip = ""* (empty string) instead of *'localhost'*?

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried the server on my phones wifi hotspot, and I was able to connect through my desktop. There must have been some firewall preventing the connection

Answer (score 0):

You bind the server to localhost:

```
ip = 'localhost'

try:
    cap = WebcamVideoStream().start()
    server = ThreadedHTTPServer((ip, 9090), CamHandler)
```

Try changing `'localhost'` to `'0.0.0.0'`. It will bind the server to all network interfaces.